# Ссылка на файл php

Tags: php

```
<?php
    foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {
       echo ""$filename\n"."<br>";
    } 
    ?>
```

У меня на странице выводится список html файлов в каталоге,как сделать чтобы эти файлы были ссылками, а не просто названиями?

Comment: добавить к ним HTML код, формирующий ссылку?

Comment: @Ипатьев И как такое сделать?

Comment: Что именно? Ссылку в HTML? Можно например открыть букварь для начинающих вебмастеров.

Comment: @Ипатьев .... ммм точно до меня дошло, HTML. точно. А я голову ломаю как в пыхе ее выдергивать

Comment: Ипатьев - можно, например, написать ответ, как это сделать, и дать ссылку на "букварь", как это сделал @koks_rs, вместо написания бесполезных для автора вопроса предложений. Или вы думаете, что если вы это знаете, то должны знать и все остальные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы отобразить ссылки нужно использовать тег **`<a>`**

```
foreach (glob("*.html") as $filename) {
     echo "<a href='$filename' >Имя файла</a><br>";
}
```

И конечно же в при этом в `$filename` у вас должен быть валидный путь к вашему файлу на сервере.

Почитать подробнее [тут](https://webref.ru/html/a)